# ios update crashed kivy-ios app

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

у меня на iphone 6s была установлена программа написана на python3 с помощью kivy-ios фреймворка.
На ios 13x потом он у меня автоматически обновился до 13.х.х, после чего приложение перестало запускаться. Нужно как-то диагностировать эту проблему, так как хочу ее выпустить в коммерческих целях. Мне же не говорить клиенту после каждой обновы ios переустанавливать приложение.
в интернете ничего не нашел, дайте совет куда копать

Comment: Я бы начал копать с https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues

Comment: простите, я не совсем понимаю что там искать

Comment: Искать вашу проблему с ios или создавать там задачу по вашей проблеме. Это можно сделать параллельно с вопросом тут, а лучше еще и на английском стеке -- там и вопросов на порядок больше (тут 232, там 7к) и процент ответов выше (тут 50%, там 75%)